# R: How to slice a window of elements in named vector

Tags: r, vector

Given the following named vector:

```
x <- c(54, 36, 67, 25, 76)
names(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

How one can extract the elements between 'b' and 'd'? I can do that for data tables with the `dplyr::select(dt, b:d)` but for some reason, I cannot find a solution for named vectors (all the examples I find are for extracting element(s) by giving all the names not a range of names)...

Comment: That's because dplyr has a functionality to look for range of columns. Base R doesn't have such functionality IIRC. There are many easy ways to solve this, but they won't be as clean as just `b:d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```r
x[which(names(x) == "b"):which(names(x) == "d")]
#>  b  c  d 
#> 36 67 25
```

The problem being that there is no guarantee in a named vector that names are unique, and if there are duplicate names the entire concept becomes meaningless.

If you wanted a complete solution that allows for tidyverse-style non-standard evaluation and sensible error messages you could have

```r
subset_named <- function(data, exp)
{
  if(missing(exp)) return(data)
  exp <- as.list(match.call())$exp
  if(is.numeric(exp)) return(data[exp])
  if(is.character(exp)) return(data[exp])
  
  tryCatch({
    ss <- suppressWarnings(eval(exp))
    return(data[ss])},
    error = function(e)
    {
      if(as.character(exp[[1]]) != ":")
        stop("`exp` must be a sequence created by ':'")
      n <- names(data)
      first <- as.character(exp[[2]])
      second <- as.character(exp[[3]])
      first_match <- which(n == first)
      second_match <- which(n == second)
      if(length(first_match) == 0)
        stop("\"", first, "\" not found in names(", 
             deparse(substitute(data)), ")")
      if(length(second_match) == 0)
        stop("\"", second, "\" not found in names(", 
             deparse(substitute(data)), ")")
      if(length(first_match) > 1) {
        warning("\"", first, 
                "\" found more than once. Using first occurence only")
        first_match <- first_match[1]
      }
      if(length(second_match) > 1) {
        warning("\"", second, 
                "\" found more than once. Using first occurence only")
        second_match <- second_match[1]
      }
      return(data[first_match:second_match])
    })
}
```

That allows the following behaviour:

```
subset_named(x, "b":"d")
#>  b  c  d 
#> 36 67 25

subset_named(x, b:d)
#>  b  c  d 
#> 36 67 25

subset_named(x, 1:3)
#>  a  b  c 
#> 54 36 67

subset_named(x, "e")
#>  e 
#> 76

subset_named(x)
#>  a  b  c  d  e 
#> 54 36 67 25 76
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
x[Reduce(`:`, which(names(x) %in% c("b", "d")))]

 b  c  d 
36 67 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` in base R :

```
x[match('b', names(x)):match('d', names(x))]
# b  c  d 
#36 67 25
```

Or if you want to use something like `b:d` convert it into dataframe as column

```
library(dplyr)

t(x) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(b:d)
```

Comment: They already have your second option in the question

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know what they mean by `dt` in their question.

Comment: dt = data table

Answer (score 1):

**1) subset** In base R this can be done using the `select` argument of `subset`.  The only catch is that only the data.frame method of `subset` supports the `select` argument but we can convert `x` to a data.frame and then convert back.  It also allows more complex specifications such as `c(b:d, d)` .

```
unlist(subset(data.frame(as.list(x)), select = b:d))
##  b  c  d 
## 36 67 25
```

**2) evalq** Another base R possibility is to create a list with the values 1, 2, 3, ... and the same names as `x` and then evaluate b:d with respect to it giving the desired indexes which can then be indexed into `x`.  This also allows complex specifications as in (1).

```
x[ evalq(b:d, setNames(as.list(seq_along(x)), names(x))) ]
##  b  c  d 
## 36 67 25
```

We could turn this into a function like this:

```
sel <- function(x, select, envir = parent.frame()) {
  ix <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(x)), names(x))
  x[ eval(substitute(select), ix, envir) ]
}

sel(x, b:d)
sel(x, c(b:c, d))
sel(x, d:b)  # reverse order
```

**3) logical condition**  Again with only base R, if the names are in sorted order, as in the question, then we can check for names between the endpoints:

```
x[names(x) >= "b" & names(x) <= "d"]
##  b  c  d 
## 36 67 25
```

**4) zoo** If the names are in ascending order, as in the question, we could create a zoo series with those names as the times and then use `window.zoo` to pick out the subseries and finally convert back.

```
library(zoo)

coredata(window(zoo(x, names(x)), start = "b", end = "d"))
##  b  c  d 
## 36 67 25
```